# Register button is displaying in different locations in differnt pages in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

If you observe in left,

In both links, REGISTER AND SIGN IN are displaying in different locations.

In home page its displaying below news letter.

In catalog view page, it's dislaying in another place. In product view page , its in  another place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your css issue.
.link-bottom {
    border: 1px solid #473D75;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    left: -370px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1700px;
}

kindly modify this or add one property. display:none.